# Smart Home Action Setting "mode" for thermostat doesn't reflect in UI

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I have a smart home action with Thermostats. The available modes are 'on' 'off' 'heat' 'cool'. Heat and cool work fine. It's just the on/off modes that aren't working properly.

When I select the "Off" mode, it continues to show the UI as if its still in heat/cool mode as shown in the following screen shot:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/snG1hGR4y9Jb7uTi8

However if I were to look at other thermostats available from other manufacturers like Zen, it properly shows the off mode UI:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/VfeY75Bf12FLuTiaA

I can confirm Nest thermostats also display correctly. I'm just wondering what I'm doing wrong. I have verified that my home graph has updated correctly with the mode as shown in the following:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/FNvcftibihxL8uFM8

I've even tried setting a hidden field called activethermostatmode that isn't documented. Addtionally what is the 'on' mode for if you can't select it in the drop down for selecting thermostat modes in the google home app.

Comment: Does querying the mode via voice work? If so, then that may be an app-related issue.

Comment: Could it be in your QUERY response, or when you are reporting state, you are still sending the `thermostatMode` as heat/cool? This is different to what you'd send for the `OnOff` trait.

Comment: @NickFelker I finally figured out the problem. It was because after I make a call to turn off a thermostat, the google UI does a query and I was not responding with the correct state information. If thats the case, what is the point of reportstate? It seems like this would be the perfect situation it would be pinging the homegraph api (ie reportstate) as opposed to doing query Intents.

Comment: @che.armstrong thanks for the suggestion, I actually removed the OnOff trait recently since it doesnt seem like it belongs with thermostats.

Answer (score 0):

The UI behavior on Google Home App and the display devices are dependent on the information which comes from Report State as well as the QUERY responses. The UI will not work properly if either of the two hasn’t been implemented correctly.

You can confirm if you have implemented both correctly using Test Suite: https://smarthome-test-suite.withgoogle.com/